# How can I view resolved variables in serverless.yml?

Tags: javascript, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Consider this simple example:

```
service: my-service

frameworkVersion: ">=1.38.0 <2.0.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-cf-vars
  - serverless-parameters
  - serverless-scriptable-plugin
  - serverless-s3-deploy

provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-1

custom:
  myVariable: "some var value"

  assets:
    auto: true
    targets:
      - bucket: ${self:custom.myVariable}
        prefix: ${self:custom.myVariable}/
        acl: private
        files:
          - source: my file
            glob: "*"
```

The problem here is - when serverless generate a json cloudformation template and uploads it into cloud-formation. I can not see what actual values were in `bucket: ${self:custom.myVariable}`.

Is there a way to output serverless template with already resolved variables?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `serverless package` command packages your entire infrastructure into the `.serverless` directory.

This is where you could see the results of any **local variables**.

Note that any CloudFormation variables (e.g. `Fn::*` config) won't have been compiled as this is handled by CloudFormation at deployment time.